# What does "Partie loin derrière" mean here?

Tags: sens, indications-de-lieu

Here is the context:

> Parti loin derrière, Sans trop de raison,
>   Tu m'as laissée hier, La fin de la saison.
>   Je ne veux plus savoir, On s'est éloignés,
>   Tu ne vas plus m'avoir, Et tout est terminé.

Comment: Have you looked it up in a dictionary ? *Partie* is the past participle of [*partir*](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/partir), and [*loin derrière*](http://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/loin+derri%C3%A8re).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niyGWxVE-e4) by Louane where she complains about a guy who left her yesterday. He went the other way (*derrière*) and far (*loin*).